# Laravel API data to an Excel file

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, phpexcel, maatwebsite-excel

I have an external API with data, what needs a X-Api-Key to use.
What I want is the following:

I have to export some data from the API to an Excel file.
If possible, I want to use Laravel but is not necessary.

I know the Excel-export of Maatwebsite, but that works only if you are getting data from a database, but not from an external API-link.

Anyone ideas?

Comment: You can use https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ you can generate your excel programmatically

Comment: Also from an external API link?